# How to prevent such websites like apkpure?

Tags: android, apk

I published many versions so far. And, the users should use the most recent app. However, [apkpure](https://apkpure.com) shows all the app list that I released.

How come this website take all the `apk` or `abb`? I don't want the website takes my applications and block the users in the app. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: one way could be to have force update functionality, to make sure all users are on the latest version of your app.

Comment: I do it, but I just want to know that we can prevent uploading those kind of website.

Comment: I don't think there would be any other way other than preventing older versions from being used, but let's see, someone might have a better suggestion :)

Comment: @c-an how you tried to contact apk pure to have them take it down?

Comment: You mean, have I contacted them? No, and there are many similar websites too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's possible to do, using one of the Android features like app bundles. This could help you to [verify non Google Play installation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/sideload-check). Or even create behavior to crash/exit in such cases.

The whole idea of the approach, it's separation application features to different bundles which could installed be installed within Google play package manager. So [you can check it's documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of android users can not access play store when removing the google restrictions, because they want apk file for install.  Third party websites publish for that kind users, As well as some desktop users want APk file specially GAME APPs. I think they not Change original APK file.